# Why does the document.body.innerText attribute of XMLHttpRequest differ from the document.body.innerText attribute in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest, innertext

## Extracting `document.body.innerText`

I'm currently working on a project to improve web accessibility for children with disabilities. However, I've recently collided with a huge roadblock while attempting to retrieve the document.body.innerText attribute from an XMLHttpRequest response.

The result from the XMLHttpRequest (responseXML.body.innerText) contains a different result than calling document.body.innerText directly from within a browser console.

### Using XMLHttpRequest

Here is the relevant code example, which currently runs on my Chrome Browser Extension (Chrome Canary v91.0.4466.0, x86_64)

```
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) return;

    // Create new request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Setup callback
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(this.responseXML.body.innerText));
    }

    // Get the HTML
    xhr.open('GET', searchResultURL);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.send();
```

When running the aforementioned code on StackOverFlow's [Twitter page](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor), you will see that the value of `this.responseXML.body.innerText` contains CSS.

> body {
> -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
> overflow-y: scroll;
> overscroll-behavior-y: none;
> }
>
> ```
> .errorContainer {
>   background-color: #FFF;
>   color: #0F1419;
>   max-width: 600px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   padding: 10%;
>   font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   font-size: 16px;
> }
>
> .errorButton {
>   margin: 3em 0;
> }
>
> .errorButton a {
>   background: #1DA1F2;
>   border-radius: 2.5em;
>   color: white;
>   padding: 1em 2em;
>   text-decoration: none;
> } ...
> ```

[Full response string](http://snippi.com/s/j3hm8l6)

#### From the Browser Console

When you retrieve the `document.body.innerText` attribute in your browser console, you will see the following value:

> "To view keyboard shortcuts, press question mark
> View keyboard shortcuts
> Home
> Explore
> Notifications
> Messages
> Profile
> More
> Tweet
> Samuel Eliot Nathanson
> @NathansonEliot
> Stack Overflow
> 3,014 Tweets
> See new Tweets
> Follow
> Stack Overflow
> @StackOverflow
> Helping write the script of the future by serving developers and all technologists.
> New York, NYstackoverflow.comJoined April 2010
> 14 Following
> 115.1K Followers
> Not followed by anyone you’re following
> Tweets
> Tweets & replies
> Media
> Likes
> Stack Overflow’s Tweets
> You might like
> freeCodeCamp.org
> @freeCodeCamp
> Follow
> DEV Community
> @ThePracticalDev
> Follow
> Show more
> Trending now
> What’s happening
> MLB
> ·
> LIVE
> Orioles at Red Sox
> Trending with Red Sox, Garrett Richards
> Politics · Trending
> HE IS ALIVE
> 38.7K Tweets
> MLB · Trending
> Cedric Mullins
> COVID-19
> ·
> LIVE
> COVID-19: News and updates for Maryland
> Premier League
> ·
> LIVE
> Manchester United vs Brighton & Hove Albion
> Trending with #MUNBHA, #MUFC
> Show more
> Terms of Service
> Privacy Policy
> Cookie Policy
> Ads info
> More
> © 2021 Twitter, Inc."

#### Why do the two methods of retrieving innerText differ?

This is unclear, so it would be great for someone with more knowledge to help out.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN documentation of `innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) (emphasis mine):

> Note: `innerText` is easily confused with `Node.textContent`, but there are important differences between the two.
> Basically, **`innerText` is aware of the rendered appearance of text**, while `textContent` is not.

However, the response document of an XHR object is never rendered, so it doesn’t have a rendered appearance.
No CSS is applied to the document, not even browser defaults.
At this point, `innerText` has the same result as `textContent`.

In order to benefit from `innerText` while still fetching the resource, you can force the browser to render the document, for example in an `<iframe>`.
It’s sufficient to simply set an `<iframe>` directly, i.e. without any XHR or Fetch request.

```js
const iframe = Object.assign(document.createElement("iframe"), {
    src: searchResultURL
  });

// This CSS ensures that the <iframe> is hidden away, but still rendered.
Object.assign(iframe.style, {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "-100%"
});
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// This load listener ensures that the fetched document is rendered (i.e. CSS applied).
iframe.addEventListener("load", ({target: {contentDocument: {body: {innerText}}}}) => {
  console.log(innerText); // Use the `innerText` here!
  iframe.remove();
});
```

Note that this and similar approaches only work if CORS headers allow access to the framed resource.
It’s not easily possible otherwise.

However, there is a security risk when doing this.
You can try using the [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attributes) to mitigate the risk, but you’d have to disable the `<iframe>` content’s JavaScript then, while still allowing `same-origin` in order to access the content.
This won’t guarantee that JS code of the content will run correctly, and getting the expected content also depends on the correct cookies and headers being sent.

It may be better to think about an approach that doesn’t rely on `innerText`’s behavior.

---

Even if (probably) not necessary, it’s also possible to mix XHR, or the more modern Fetch, into this, just so you can see a few alternative approaches.

The following code uses the more modern [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of your original XHR approach.

```js
fetch(searchResultURL)
  .then((resp) => resp.text())
  .then((text) => {
    const iframe = Object.assign(document.createElement("iframe"), {
        srcdoc: text
      });
    
    Object.assign(iframe.style, {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "-100%"
    });
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.addEventListener("load", ({target: {contentDocument: {body: {innerText}}}}) => {
      console.log(innerText);
      iframe.remove();
    });
  });
```

Or, using your original XHR approach and more backward compatible code for older browsers:

- Remove `xhr.responseType = 'document';`.
- Use this as the `load` listener (use `addEventListener` instead):

  ```js
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    iframe.srcdoc = this.responseText;
    iframe.style.position = "absolute";
    iframe.style.top = "-100%";
    iframe.addEventListener("load", function(){
      console.log(this.contentDocument.body.innerText);
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  });
  ```

This still requires [`srcdoc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) to work in your browser.
Alternatively, there’s the [Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) which has better browser support:

- In the Fetch approach:

  - Replace `resp.text()` by `resp.blob()`
  - Replace `.then((text) => {`…`}` by `.then((blob) => {`…`}`
  - Replace `srcdoc: text` by `src: URL.createObjectURL(blob)`
- Or in the XHR approach:

  - Replace `iframe.srcdoc = this.responseText;` by `iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ this.responseText ], { type: "text/html" }));`

Comment: At the point where you're loading an iframe, you might as well drop the XHR/fetch call and directly set the iframe's `src` to the URL :-) Also notice that this is a potential security issue, as rendering the document in an iframe will execute scripts contained in it.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I’ve included the simpler approach without the Fetch near the top of the answer in my edit, but I can clarify that in another edit. Do you know if it is the case that access to a page in an `<iframe>` is possible _iff_ Fetch or XHR can fetch the page; or could there be some differences in the two approaches? Yes, the security issue is there; it can be mitigated with the `sandbox` attribute, but I think the final paragraph of the answer still stands: this still doesn’t guarantee success.

Comment: Ah, perfect, I had not seen the edit when I wrote the comment.